# como definir array multidimencional con urls?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
var urlrefi = 16;

globales[16][0] = "http://queen0.com.mx/movil/Servicios.svc/getEstadosReferenciasPorClienteDetalle";
globales[16][1] = "http://queen1.com.mx/movil/Servicios.svc/getEstadosReferenciasPorClienteDetalle";
globales[16][2] = "http://quen2.com.mx/movil/Servicios.svc/getEstadosReferenciasPorClienteDetalle";
globales[16][3] = "http://queen3.com.mx/movil/Servicios.svc/getEstadosReferenciasPorClienteDetalle";
```

Cuando la ocupo de la siguiente forma   el navegador me dice que esta undefined y no me deja usar sus propiedades

```
var vg = globales[urlrefi][val];
```

Comment: Te falta definir e inicializar la variable "globales" como una matriz 2D, así rapido y suponiendo que son 17 posiciones (0-16) añade al inicio:
var globales=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]];

Comment: esto me sirve ?

 globales = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < oficinas; i++)
    globales[i] = new Array();

Comment: Seria la idea, si, con un 'var' delante.

Comment: ya lo hice y no funciono tristemente "/

Comment: ¿Ya has declarado e inicializado también la variable 'oficinas'?
Te pongo un ejemplo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo, te falta definir el array de globales:

```
let globales = [
    [],
    [],
    []
]

// Ahora, puedo hacer la asignación:
globales[0][0] = "http://tuUrl.com";
globales[0][1] = "http://otroUrl.com";
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Te falta declarar e inicializar las variables.
Por ejemplo:

```js
var oficinas=17;
var globales = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < oficinas; i++) globales[i] = new Array();
globales[16][0] = "http://queen0.com.mx/movil/Servicios.svc/getEstadosReferenciasPorClienteDetalle";
globales[16][1] = "http://queen1.com.mx/movil/Servicios.svc/getEstadosReferenciasPorClienteDetalle";
globales[16][2] = "http://quen2.com.mx/movil/Servicios.svc/getEstadosReferenciasPorClienteDetalle";
globales[16][3] = "http://queen3.com.mx/movil/Servicios.svc/getEstadosReferenciasPorClienteDetalle";
console.log (globales[16][3]);
```

Comment: funciono gracias!